# Concurrent execution of C# code results in duplicate db entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Well, I have this code:

```
var companyId = 1;
var categoryId = 1;
var item = _dbContext.FirstOrDefault(i => 
     i.CompanyId == companyId && i.CategoryId == categoryId);


if (item == null) {
    var newItem = new Item() 
    {
        CategoryId = companyId,
        CompanyId = categoryId,
        // some other properties
    };
    _dbContext.Items.Add(newItem);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
else 
{
    // update some properties of the item (not CompanyId or CategoryId)
    item.xyz = "new Value"
    _dbContext.Items.Update(item);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is the only piece of code where I access `Items` table. I want to make sure no duplicate entries are made for `CompanyId-CategoryId` combination, that is to say, this combination should be unique. But even though the code checks for the existence before insertion, how do I end up having duplicate entries in the database?

Please ignore everything else (the architecture, the use of DB Context etc since I have just written this simple code to understand the problem). Also, I know I can implement this thing at DB level and make columns combination unique, but is there any way to do this in application code (in C#)? I am using EF, if that's important. Why exactly is this problem caused, multithreading?

Please help me understand this issue or give me some directions to what further I should read in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: Both threads try to find the existing connection, fails, and then adds one, both of them. You will have to make sure this specific part of the code (at least) doesn't run in parallel, but is sequential.

Comment: Thanks. So multi-threading. Right. Any efficient solution for this?

Comment: _"...but is there any way to do this in application code..."_ - well you could, but then you are essentially doing what a DB is designed for whether it be table constraints or a stored proc.  Doing so in code is just going to lead lead to noise

Comment: At least put a unique constraint on your DB for the combination of those columns.

Comment: where are you creating your dbcontext.

Comment: Getting the instance in constructor from AspNet Core DI container. Used the `services.AddDbContext` in `Startup.cs`

Comment: what is the scope of the Dbcontext . As it is not thread safe. Dbcontext should be created per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in application code, then you are going to have to force single threading somewhere.  One way to do this would be to use locking to produce a section of code that only one thread can enter at a time.  You then would re-check existence of the record and *if still null* perform your insert.  It would look something like this:

```
// declared at class level
private static readonly object ItemCreationSyncLock = new object();

public void MyMethodThatCreatesAnItem()
{
    // ... setup code ...
    var item = _dbContext.Items.FirstOrDefault(itm => item.Name == criteria);
    if(item == null)
    {
        lock(ItemCreationSyncLock)
        {
            item = _dbContext.Items.FirstOfDefault(itm => item.Name == criteria);
            if(item == null)
            {
                item = new Item { Name = criteria };
                _dbContext.Items.Add(item);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I covered the "how" of avoiding the duplicate entry in the application code, but it is important to realize that even as a backup to this you would still want to enforce a unique constraint at the database level if you really want to ensure duplicates cannot exist.  I am capable of defeating the guard that I just showed you by scaling the application out to multiple instances, whether using web garden/farm or scaling to additional instances on Azure.

Comment: Wow. Right. I didn't imagine the consequences in a web farm. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a lock in C# will only work if you have a single web server. If you have a farm, then each instance of your application will have its own ItemCreationSyncLock.

To create a synchronization lock in the database, for SQL Server is as simple as this:

```
    using (var db = new Db())
    using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_getapplock 'MyAppLock','exclusive';");

        //only one thread across all application instances will execute this code at one time

        tran.Commit();
    }
```